# Вопрос про arduino

Tags: arduino

Сразу говорю, в теме робототехники я новичок и ни разу не делал что-то на ардуино. Но сегодня решил начать изучать эту тему.

Если я правильно понял - ардуино это плата, в которую мы с компьютера загружаем программу, и процессор на этой плате её выполняет, посылая сигналы на различные порты.

У меня появилась идея сделать что-то вроде умного светофора, поставить палочку с лампочками - это сам светофор, на которую нужно посылать сигналы в зависимости от ситуации на дороге. А вот ситуацию на дороге я буду получать с камеры, и мне кажется, что процессор ардуино не справиться с обработкой видео. Зато может справиться компьютер. Вот и вопрос - могу ли я построить взаимодействие компьютера и ардуино так, что комп обрабатывает видео и посылает сигналы ардуино, а оно в свои очередь управляет светофором?

Или может это можно реализовать напрямую без ардуино?

Comment: да, можешь... с ардуиной для неофита будет самое простое: она эмулирует последовательный порт, так что ни с написанием дров заморачиваться не надо... при желании с обычного компьютера можно управлять чем-либо совсем простым через последовательный порт, например, если он всё ещё есть конечно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо)